# how can i create a rest api with a key system? and json

Tags: node.js, json, api, rest, express

I try to make my api.

it should look like this:
http://test.com/api/genpw/KEY=key/TYPE=BASE64/HEX

the request should come back like this:

```
{
  APIKEY: "KEY",
  TYPE: "BASE64 / HEX"
  PASSWORD: "GENERATED PW"
}
```

How do I do this and how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think these parameters should be part of the URL. Following the REST API standard, they should be query parameters and the URL must be: http://test.com/api/genpw?key=some-value&type=base64

Example how to get query parameters in express:

```
app.get('/api/content', async (req, res) => {
  const {key, type, password} = req.query;
  res.send('success');
}
```